# What is the best way to get an element's tag name in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I want to get the name of a certain tag (to tell whether it is a div/input/span/p/so on)

I found that there are 3 different attributes that give me the tag name:

`tagName`, `nodeName`, and `localName`

My question is: Which one is the most supported in all browsers? And/or is there a method to get the tag name in Prototype (I looked but couldn't find one)?

Comment: You should ignore `localName` as it's now obsolete ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/localName)).

Comment: There is no longer any mention of `localName` being deprecated on the MDN article.

Comment: Confirming, no mention of deprecation there. [As long as you're not using IE8, you're in the clear.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_localname)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`nodeName` is the most consistent here.  I would suggest you [take a minute and read this post for a few differences and inconsistencies with `tagName`](http://aleembawany.com/2009/02/11/tagname-vs-nodename/) if you're more curious as to why.

For the prototype part of the question...it's a JavaScript property, just `this.nodeName` should work or `element.nodeName`, whatever your element's called in the current function should work.

Comment: Nice link to the article, +1 :). As for the prototype function, I just meant is there a function that determines which property is best to use based on the browser, like using `update()` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: @webdestroya - Since this one works consistently across browsers, no need to add any overhead in the library, for example jQuery doesn't have any method for this either :)

Comment: learner:  localName doesn't work in IE.  For a TH element, I tried alert(this.localName), got "th" in Firefox;  got "undefined" in IE 7. Didn't try newer versions of IE.